# How to add and remove specific text to ColB if ColA is filled or not, using script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have var name = 'Name', and i need to fill ColB with that name if ColA is filled and clear ColB if text is removed from ColA. It will be great if it works "onEdit"! Big thanks!

Ok i got it! Thanks for the help! The working code below:

```
 var range = e.range;
 if (range.getColumn() == 2 && e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'Покупатели')  
 {
 if (!range.isBlank()) {
  sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 7).setValue(manager);
  }
  else {
  sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 7).setValue('');
 }
 } 
 }
```

Comment: Can you share what you have so far?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yMfdx7UOlDlpP_alblzaOzzXc7efIGwcZeS8FjO4jkE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I hate to be a pain but give a before and after example. It is helpful if you format your question with the code that you have so far.

Comment: I attached a piece of code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go -

```
var name = 'Name';
var sheetName = 'Sheet1';

function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == sheetName) {
    if (range.getColumn() == 1) {
      if (!range.isBlank()) {
        ss.getRange(range.getRow(), 2).setValue(name);
      } else {
        ss.getRange(range.getRow(), 2).setValue('');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this setup only takes into account the first and second columns (i.e. Col 1/A & Col 2/B). Hope this helps!

Comment: It works great, thank you, but what if i need it to work onlyt at specific sheet? is it possible?

Comment: I don’t quite understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @VladimirMelnikov - done; have updated my answer to ensure changes happen only to a specific sheet. Please change the `sheetName` variable, as required.