# On-Change Trigger for a macro restriced from one sheet only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to run a macro on the on-change trigger. It's working fine but the problem is that if any data is changed in the whole file, the macro gets triggered. My file has 6 sheets and I want the macro to run only if data is changed in one sheet only, or if a new row is added to that sheet.

Forms Responses 1 is the name of sheet in which I want to have this trigger

Following is the code for macro

```
function SECONDTRY() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('H2').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Bank Account Limit'), true);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:H').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(1, 0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows() - 1).sort({column: 1, ascending: false});
  spreadsheet.getRange('H2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('H3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D2:H2').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Bank Account Limit'), true);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Bank Accounts Given'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('2:2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Form Responses 1\'!D2:H2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Comment: Welcome, Saad!  Does this answer to a similar question help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59337798/9593895

Comment: No this doesn't help, anyhow thanks for your input.

Comment: While this is not the issue you raised, please take into account that `onChange` will only fire on **user** changes, not whenever the sheet content changes. So the question would be, what actions do you expect will trigger this? If you are expecting a Form submission to trigger this, you'll have to install another type of trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with something like this:

```
function onMyChange(e) {
  const shts=['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3'];
  const sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if(shts.indexOf(sh.getName()==-1){return}
```

That way only the sheets listed in the array will run the remainder of the function and you can add to those sheets as needed.  In the case of onChange there is no event parameter documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) to obtain the the current sheet.  But if you use Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) in the beginning of the code and find  a range or a source then you use one of them to obtain the current sheet.

Comment: I think I was unable to clearly describe the problem so let me rephrase it. I have a macro named "SECONDTRY". Currently it executes on a trigger of on-change. Whenever value of any cell in the file changes, it automatically executes. Now I want to restrict it to only one sheet, rather the whole file. So it should trigger when there is any change in one sheet only that is "Form Resposnses 1".

Comment: then `const shts=['Your Sheet Name'];` [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: By the way the trigger does not fire on any change.  It only fires on user changes.

Comment: Yes it fires on user changes within the whole file. I need it to fire only when there is a change in sheet name "Form Resposnses 1"